# set column headers in knockout grid dynamically

Tags: dynamic, knockout.js, header, grid

I have a requirement where I need to set column headers in knockout grid dynamically. I tried using observable but didn't help as initially whatever value is assigned that only it is keeping .

```
self.ItemsGrid = new ko.grid.viewModel({
        columns: [
            { field: "ItemCode", headerText: self.lblItemHeader, sort: self.GetItems },
            { field: "Mark", headerText: self.lblMark, sort: self.GetItems },
            { field: "Equipment", headerText: self.lblEquipment, sort: self.GetItems },
            { field: "RiskCategory", headerText: lblRiskCateg, sort: self.GetItems },
            { field: "Region", headerText: lblRegion, sort: self.GetItems },
            { field: "SerialNumber", headerText: lblSerialNo, sort: self.GetItems },
            { field: "RiskArea", headerText: lblRiskArea, sort: self.GetItems },
            { field: "RiskType", headerText: lblRiskType, sort: self.GetItems },
            { field: "RiskValue", headerText: lblRiskVal, sort: self.GetItems },
            { field: "", headerText: '' }
        ],
        rowTemplate: "itemsTemplate",
        paginate: self.GetItems,
        pageSizeChange: self.GetItems,
        pageSizeOptions: [10, 20, 30],
        currentPageIndex: 1,
        root: self
    });
```

For first three columns I have used observables. These observables I am setting in a function and value is getting updated for these observables but still does not reflect in header.

Comment: You say you're using observables but looking at the code that doesn't seem to be the case... can you explain what you mean by "for the first three columns I have used observables"?

Comment: self.lblItemHeader, self.lblMark and self.lblEquipment are observables. I am setting values to these observables in another function which is called before data is bind to Itemsgrid . PFB code snipped for same.self.LoadItemFieldsList = function (data) {
     self.DocumentsDetails().ItemFieldsList(data);
     self.lblItemHeader = data[0].ItemField;
     self.lblMark = data[1].ItemField;
    };

Comment: Itemtemplate is set as below:
<script type="text/html" id="itemsTemplate">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="headerText: self.lblItemHeader, text: ItemCode"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Mark"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Equipment"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: RiskCategory"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Region"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: SerialNumber"></td>

Comment: Post this information in the question. The more information you provide in the question the more likely it can be answered.